# html5 facebook and special characters

Tags: facebook, html, addthis

I am using addthis and including facebook sharing button. I currently use html5 and when I include:
`xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"` in my html tag, this causes special characters such as ’  the left apostrophe to show up as three question marks.

I know replacing this with entity would fix this but data is entered via a text box in a cms, by users. Removing the xmlns items fixes this. The page is encoded in utf8.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" > <!--<![endif]--> 
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Bart

Comment: Are you using a UTF-8 declaration on your page?

Comment: I updated the question to show the code I am using

Comment: You've got nested comments in your IE8 section.

Comment: This problem occurs outside of IE also though...

Comment: Can you provide a live URL to see this on?

Comment: It appears to not be an issue anymore.. thanks for your help